# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \arcsin\frac{k}{n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \arcsin\frac{k}{n^2}$$
Any hints on how to approach this problem in the first place? The answer should be $\frac12$.

I tried transforming it so I can use a Riemann sum, but it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\arcsin\dfrac k{n^2}\approx\lim\dfrac k{n^2}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Following lab bhattacharjee's hint, $\arcsin x=x+O(x^3)$ for small $x$. Therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\arcsin\frac k{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac k{n^2}+O\left(\sum_{k=1}^n
\frac {k^3}{n^6}\right).$$
In that second sum, the largest term is $1/n^3$ and there are $n$ terms so that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\arcsin\frac k{n^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac k{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
etc.

Comment: Thank you a whole freaking lot!! Do you have any idea how is this method called?

Comment: @rares_st I don't think it's special enough to have a name.